Border radius of a linear-gradient background
I'm using a background to simulate a 2 color underline:
background: linear-gradient(
              to right,
              $green 0%, 
              $green 75%, 
              $red 75%, 
              $red
) no-repeat 0 100%;
background-size: 100% 4px;

This creates a nice underline but with square corners. How can I create round corners?
What I've got vs what I want.

Simple border-radius doesn't work.


.line {
width: 200px;
height: 20px;
display: table;
  position: relative;
background: linear-gradient(
                  to right,
                  green 0%, /* Green */
                  green 75%, /* Green */
                  red 75%, /* Red */
                  red /* Red */
  ) no-repeat 0 100%;
  background-size: 100% 10px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
 }
<div class="line"></div>




Nope, you cannot, unless you turn it into an SVG or something.

My guess is that if the gradient effect is to be rounded and not the element, you will need multiple gradients. I'd be thinking radial gradients at each end or something similar.

Can't you simply wrap it in a parent element, setting it to overflow: hidden;, and apply the border-radius on it?

@prettyInPink I'll think about it, I'm not entirely sure how to do it, as this is a standalone class that I apply to different objects (when I need an underline). I would have to modify the html everywhere I need it to do it this way?

@Paulie_D yeah, I've tried that approach but I cannot figure that out.



.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
}

.line::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  background: linear-gradient( to right, green 0%, green 75%, red 75%, red);
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* Adjust to your desired border radius */
}
<div class="line"></div>



remove the unnecessary display: table property.
and add a pseudo-element ::after to the .line class to create the underline and apply the linear-gradient background to the pseudo-element.
add border-radius property to the pseudo-element to round the corners
